# Como chamar um método não estático dentro de uma classe estática?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Eu possuo a seguinte método/função e preciso chamar o método/função `criaTimerTendencia` que esta dentro da classe `TagAnalogicaAtiva`.

```
private static void VerificaEnvioDeMensagensSignalR(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ExisteTendenciaParaTag)
    {
        TagAnalogicaAtiva.criaTimerTendencia();//preciso chamar este metodo/função 
    }
}
```

Segue abaixo o código do método `criaTimerTendencia()`

```
class TagAnalogicaAtiva : TagAtiva
{
    public void criaTimerTendencia()
    {
        var tendencia = Processamento.PegaTendencia(IdTag);
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(tendencia.TempoDeColeta);
        timer.Elapsed += insereTendenciaDB;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
     }
}
```

Só que esta acontecendo o seguinte erro:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TagAnalogicaAtiva.criaTimerTendencia()'

Como resolvo este problema?

Comment: qual o tipo de `sender`? tenta fazer um `var tipo = sender.GetType()` para ver o tipo o `sender`.

Comment: tenta isso 
`TagAnalogicaAtiva tag = new TagAnalogicaAtiva ();`
`tag.criaTimerTendencia();`

Ou muda 

`public static void criaTimerTendencia()`

Comment: Onde está declarada a variável `timer`? Pode colocar mais partes desta classe, especialmente o uso do `timer`?

Comment: por quê você não criou um obj de TagAnalogicaAtiva na classe estática e acessou ele ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neste caso, não faz diferença se a classe "de fora" é estática ou não. O problema do código é que você está chamando um método **não-estático** de `TagAnalogicaAtiva` sem antes criar uma instância de `TagAnalogicaAtiva`, isso nunca vai funcionar.

Membros estáticos são acessíveis através da classe e não de instâncias. Membros não-estáticos são acessíveis através de instâncias de determinada classe.

Imagine que exista na classe `TagAnalogicaAtiva` os métodos `FazerAlgo()` e `FazerAlgoEstatico()` sendo eles, respectivamente, não-estático e estático.

Para chamar o método `FazerAlgo()` é necessário ter uma instância de `TagAnalogicaAtiva`, no outro caso isso não é necessário.

```
var tag = new TagAnalogicaAtiva();
tag.FazerAlgo();

TagAnalogicaAtiva.FazerAlgoEstatico(); // Funciona
```

Então é necessário criar uma instância de `TagAnalogicaAtiva` para acessar o método `criaTimerTendencia()`, já que ele é não-estático.

```
var tag = new TagAnalogicaAtiva();
tag.criaTimerTendencia();
```

Answer (score 2):

para acessar o método não estático, você deve instanciar um objeto da classe:

```
TagAnalogicaAtiva obj = new TagAnalogicaAtiva();
obj.criaTimerTendencia();
```